# Check if Windows Username and Password is correct in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ntlm

I have a NodeJs application with certain parameters. Some of them are a Username and a Password.

I am trying to figure out whether there is a way I can check if the Password provided for the given UserName is the right one according to Active Directory.

On my C# application, I can do something like this

```
bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(UserName, Password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

but... how to do something similar in NodeJs?

**EDIT**:
In other words, I am trying to figure out given a UserName and Password that are part of a Windows domain, check whether the password is correct.

Example:
**UserName**: user@domain.com
**PassWord**: password123!

I am wondering how to validate windows domain credentials using NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Active Directory lib that you can use in NodeJS.

A few samples include:

- `node-sspi` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi)
- `passport-windowsauth` from [here](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth)
- `ldapjs` from [here](http://ldapjs.org/client.html) with [an example of integration](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-use-active-directory-authentication-authorization-node.js-bluemix-application/index.html)
- `LDAP` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/LDAP)

Basically, through LDAP ([packages of LDAP on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ldap)) you could check if you are able to make a simple `bind` with the Active Directory, and therefore if the credentials are working.